# A FTP text editor on Windows

Tags: ftp, text-editor

I noticed in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIxDJof7xxQ - that Ian uses a text editor that enables maintaining a FTP connection. Whenever he saves the text-file (which is a HTML file in his case), that update gets sent to the server automatically. I would love to be able to do that.

As for now I use Notepad++ in which I predominately create HTML and JavaScript text files. My machine is Windows 7. I have a web-hosting account (ASP.net) for my domains, which also includes a FTP account, of course.

I am looking for a **lightweight** text-editor that enables the functionality which can be seen in the above video - I want to be able to open a text-file (remotely via FTP), edit it, and then just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to send the updated version to the remote server via FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't Notepad++ have a plug-in for this?  I think I noticed that a while back...

Not quite what you're looking for, the FileZilla FTP client will detect that the file being edited has been modified and prompts you to upload it (maybe that can be made automatic also).

Comment: Didn't know about such a plug-in. I'm going to check it out.

Comment: Here's a discussion about the Notepad++ options: http://superuser.com/questions/47497/notepad-ftp-best-solution

Comment: I installed the FTP_synchronize plug-in. It works splendid. :) However, I heard from the guys (over at SuperUser) that files tend to get lost when manipulating them via FTP.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it works (mostly!)

Comment: FileZilla is now a crapware. Look for this on the internet and you will see reports. That's a pity.

Answer (score 5):

The [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite/) editor does seamless FTP editing.

Comment: +1 The FTP editing works well :)

Answer (score 0):

Vim can do this, using the ftp plugin.

http://www.vim.org/

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is the editor you are looking for.  I use it all the time to edit files on LAMP servers with FTP

under plugins open nppftp and click show, and the command interface for the ftp engine will appear.